# My iPhone is locked with an "icloud backup" message and it won't go away

Tags: icloud

I know you're supposed to press the home and lock button and restart it but my iPhones lock button has been broken for awhile and I can't afford to fix it or fix it myself.

Comment: Feel free to edit this to make it clear how your situation is different than the others looking for general solutions to the lock button failing. After an edit, this gets reviewed for reopening without you needing to take any further action.

Answer (score 0):

If the home button is broken, you'll just wait for the battery to die.

Comment: Without details, we don't know if the message will go away when the phone starts again.